# Why does Eclipse auto-generate a servlet constructor by default?

Tags: eclipse, servlets, jakarta-ee

As far as I understand, there is no point, in most cases, in creating a servlet constructor: the web container will call the argument-less constructor of the parent class, and it is recommended to use the `init` method to perform servlet initialization tasks.

However, the Eclipse Java EE helper for creating a new Servlet, by default, generates a constructor:
[image: servlet1]

Which gives this:

```
/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public MyServlet() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
```

Suggesting that I should complete the constructor. Why is that?

Comment: Is the preselection of the checkboxes always the same here or is the selection remembered from the last time? To support different programming styles, it would be best to save the last selection. Or what do you think?

Comment: The preselection is always the same.

Comment: [1] While I agree that servlets do not usually need a constructor, this is not an appropriate question for Stack Overflow. You are asking why a particular GUI design decision of very minor importance was made by some Eclipse developer(s), and only they can answer that question. [2] If you truly care about this, and want the default option setting to be unchecked, I suggest that you [raise a feature request on Bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/). [3] Your title is incorrect. Eclipse does not _"auto-generate a servlet constructor"_; the user decides whether a constructor is generated.

Comment: Well, this GUI design decision was enough to shatter the confidence I have in my understanding of a servlet lifecycle. If there was any good reason for it to be that way, that question would fit SO. I also tried to see if it would be better for Software Engineering but I reckoned not. I admit the title is slightly wrong, it is however the default behavior. Have mercy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree that the preselection of the **checkboxes in the *Create Servlet* dialog** could be improved. Please [report this to Eclipse WTP Java EE Tools](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=WTP%20Java%20EE%20Tools&component=jst.j2ee) as a feature request.

The comment **`// TODO Auto-generated constructor stub`** comes from the *Constructor body* code template, which can be changed and applies not only to Servlets but also to other Java classes:

***Window > Preferences: Java > Code Style > Code Templates: Code > Constructor body***